# Situation where it is imperative to have Windows as part of dual boot?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Rather than a dual boot system, I'd prefer installing just Ubuntu and using Windows via a virtual box.

Before doing that, I just wanted to know if there is any situation where it is absolutely necessary to have Windows installed as the first and primary OS? I don't want to run into a situation where I install only Ubuntu and when I startup my virtual box in Ubuntu and run Windows inside the virtual box, some application in Windows or some hardware functionality does not work because Windows is installed in a virtual box.

Speed of running and RAM consumption are not an issue.

Comment: Anything that requires direct access to weird hardware, anything that doesn't run in visualised environments (some programs do exist with this weird gotcha).

Comment: @djsmiley2k yes, this is what I wanted to know. What are the "weird hardware" and which programs (at least some examples) don't run in virtualized environments?

Comment: I voted to close this question since it is the prime example of an *opinion-based* discussion, in my humble opinion, as the first two answers and following comments clearly show.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, IMHO, the question is objective enough, asking us what things cannot be done under Windows inside a virtual machine that can be done with a full install.

Comment: @Nav Mostly, it's just performance. Windows in a VM performs not-as-well as Windows directly installed

Comment: However, it’s sort of like a software recommendation. “Give situation” vs ”Give software” – not that much difference. Except this is even more open-ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list some, you could have issues with programs that need the following:

- Low-level access to hardware, e.g. trying to access your wireless card to capture packets promiscuously (can't imagine why you would want to do that when you have Linux, though) or maybe flashing your BIOS for crude examples.
- Access to your disk partitions for data recovery etc. (again relates to low-level hardware access)
- Some specialized hardware (say even some webcams) may not work through virtual machines, at least without extensive configuration. Or if you have an Nvidia graphics card, you probably won't be able to use CUDA etc.
- Some (can't cite any, but haven't heard, would love examples) software makers forbid you from virtualizing their software, so this could be a potential legal issue.
- Applications where security is important, though it shouldn't generally be an issue.

These are some of the problems I can think of, but you could possibly find some more. Of course, performance would be the biggest thing to worry about, but if you are not concerned with it, then you should be able to do pretty much everything.